Output views {{ dump() }} value in views-view-unformatted--xyz.twig
How do I output the items_per_page value in the screenshot to my views-view-unformatted--xyz.html.twig template?
Running {{ dump() }} on views-view-unformatted--xyz.html.twig shows the attached.
I'd like to output Items = 12 in my webpage. Thanks


Use a preprocess function to pass the items_per_page value to your custom Twig template.
function YOUR_THEME_preprocess_views_view(&$variables) {
  // Check for the specific view and display
  if ($variables['view']->id() === 'xyz' && $variables['view']->current_display === 'default') {
    // Get the items per page setting from the view's query
    $items_per_page = $variables['view']->getItemsPerPage();
    
    // Pass it to the template
    $variables['items_per_page'] = $items_per_page;
  }
}


Is xyz the machine name of my view e.g news_articles? I updated YOUR_THEME and tried adding {{ items_per_page }} to views-view-unformatted....html.twig but got no output unfortunately. Thanks

Yes, xyz is the machine name of the view and current_display is the machine name of the block found under the advanced options.
